# Any shortcut for proportional editing mode and the falloff types?

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut, proportional-editing

I know the <kbd>O</kbd> button is the shortcut for enabling the ***Proportional Editing*** mode. What if I want to change its type to *Connected* type using a shortcut?
[image]

Are there any shortcuts for enabling the proportional editing modes (such as *Connected* and *Projected (2D)*) and falloff types (such as *Sphere*, *Linear*, *Random* etc.)?
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can turn on **Connected** *Proportional Editing* by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

[image: gif_1]

Note that if pressing that shortcut again it will turn off *Proportional Editing* at all. If you'd like just to turn off **Connected** but leave *Proportional Editing* you should press <kbd>O</kbd> again.

You can loop through all the falloff types by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

[image: gif_2]

Comment: Thanks @Mr Zak. Very intuitive shortcuts. Why I haven't found it out by myself? Wonder why there is no shortcut for a 'Projected (2D) mode' though?

Comment: @Gonzou I guess that was never finished? There's also no separate icon for projected 2D mode, which can be confusing. [I tried designing an icon for it](https://developer.blender.org/D774), but it [wasn't very good](https://dev-files.blender.org/file/data/z6dawv2wf5oi3zgurmpy/PHID-FILE-7cwzrszq5e7x3mykt4tf/show.php.png) :P

Comment: @gandalf3 I think you proposed a very simple, consistent and compact (with other icons) graphical solution for a 'Projected (2D) mode'. I like it :). Any chances it'll appear in a future Blender version releases?

Comment: @Gonzou Doesn't seem like it.. There is [another proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ScPMbHv8WRCU2znB7IU2l-W9hH-NLs5weQKLkjqmgpA/edit#heading=h.qbvifmkpio8p) to entirely change the way picking proportional editing modes works.