# How to select proportional editing options

Tags: interface

Using Blender 2.76, I am trying to understand proportional editing options from https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html

How can I select enable or projected ?

At the moment, I can only select connected or disable.

EDIT:

I got it: selection is actually changing but I was expecting to see the selected option in the dropdown (like a blue background).

Comment: On the header at the bottom of the 3D view, there's a dropdown with the options.

Comment: Yes, that's the point ... when I select enable or connected in this dropdown, it selects connected.

Comment: Oh, ok; it wasn't clear from the question

Comment: This answer may help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35213/any-shortcut-for-proportional-editing-mode-and-the-falloff-types